# How to Hide Modal Box After User Login

Tags: javascript, vue.js

When user click log in button on my navigation a modal box pop up after user log in the modal box does not disappear.

How can i hide remove the modal box when users click log in

Home.vue

```
    <div id="myModal1" class="modal  centered-modal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog login_dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <i class="fa_icon form_close"></i>
          </button>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="ms_register_img">
              <img src="images/register_img.png" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div class="ms_register_form">
              <h2>Log In</h2>
              <form @submit.prevent="submit">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email" class="form-control" v-model="form.email">
                  <span class="form_icon">
                  <i class="fa_icon form-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Your Password" class="form-control" v-model="form.password">
                  <span class="form_icon">
                  <i class="fa_icon form-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  </span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="reg_ms_btn" type="submit">Log In</button>
                </div>
              </form>   
              <div class="remember_checkbox">
                <label>Keep me signed in
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="popup_forgot">
                <a href="#">Forgot Password ?</a>
              </div>
              <p>Don't Have An Account? <a href="#myModal" data-toggle="modal" class="ms_modal1 hideCurrentModel">register here</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add v-if="userLoggedIn" or v-if="user.userName != 'guest'".

I'm assuming here that not logged users have 'guest' as username.

```
<div v-if="userLoggedIn" id="myModal1" class="modal  centered-modal" role="dialog">
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a toggle and target property to the login button, this is so that when clicked it will close the modal.
Edit the login div like so:

```html
<div class="form-group" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="myModal1">
  <buttonclas="reg_ms_btn" type="submit"> Log In</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Ensure the data-target value is equal to the 'id' you labeled the entire modal.